# react-bootstrap form getting "Row is not defined" error

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) in my React project and following their documented examples to create a form. If I understand correctly, I only need to import `form` to get all the Form functionality:

```
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
```

Specifically, I'm following [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/form-control/#readonly-plain-text) pretty simple example:

```
<Form>
  <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formPlaintextEmail">
    <Form.Label column sm="2">
      Email
    </Form.Label>
    <Col sm="10">
      <Form.Control plaintext readOnly defaultValue="email@example.com" />
    </Col>
  </Form.Group>

  <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formPlaintextPassword">
    <Form.Label column sm="2">
      Password
    </Form.Label>
    <Col sm="10">
      <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </Col>
  </Form.Group>
</Form>
```

However, I get the following error in Chrome DevTools:

```
MyComponent.jsx:430 Uncaught ReferenceError: Row is not defined
```

I tried importing row, but that doesn't resolve the error. Any ideas what's missing?

Seems to me either their documented example is incomplete or broken, or there's some additional import I need to add to use react-bootstrap.

**Update 2022**: I updated the above link to the example, which had changed. Interestingly, the examples still [only mentions](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/form-control/#form-control-props) importing Form (import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form') and leave out the surprising need to also import Row and Col.

Comment: `Row` is a prop for the component. You should pass `Row` as a prop.

Comment: Actually `Row` is a component from bootstrap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should import `Row`, `Col` and `Form` from `react-bootstrap`. Refer this `MDN` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for more about JavaScript `imports`.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Col, Row, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formPlaintextEmail">
        <Form.Label column sm="2">
          Email
        </Form.Label>
        <Col sm="10">
          <Form.Control plaintext readOnly defaultValue="email@example.com" />
        </Col>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formPlaintextPassword">
        <Form.Label column sm="2">
          Password
        </Form.Label>
        <Col sm="10">
          <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </Col>
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-stonebraker-boqcc) is the working link.

Comment: Wow, that works. Thanks! I don't see that in their documentation. It mentions importing Form ("import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'). But I guess Col, Row, etc., need to be imported separately.

Comment: They have exported the `Form`, `Row`, `Col`, etc in https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/index.js But I dont know why the documentation is not updated.